# Cannot install mbstring php conflict

Tags: php, php-5.6, mbstring

I am trying to install php-mbstring with php 5.6 and I get this error:

```
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have attempted to install php56-mbstring, but I get the following. I am not sure if this means it is already installed or not:

```
Nothing to do
```

What is the most appropriate package to install? Which one should I be trying to resolve and how can I resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I run into same problem with my server running PHP 5.6.17. For me it seems that the extension that I was looking for was **php56w-mbstring.x86_64**

It can be found from **webtatic** repository. I don't remember enabling that by myself, but in case it is missing here is the instructions how to enable said repo: http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-install-webtatic-repository/

You can list available repos in your server by command **yum repolist**

To search if your repos has something related to mbstring use command **yum list *mbstring***

So solution for me was this: **yum install php56w-mbstring.x86_64**

Finally restart Apache: **service httpd restart**

By the way, I am running CentOS server so your commands might be slightly different on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the module to your PHP.ini file `extension=php_mbstring.dll`

Comment: Can you confirm the command you are using / OS / PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

I tried and tried everything until i came to this link. https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#debian-setup

I run /usr/sbin/pma-configure and bam I had phpmyadmin working without the mbstring error

there is so many setups now that it is hard to find the one you need.

running ubuntu 14.04 with 4 versions of php installed with virtualmin webmin cp. Debian and Ubuntu changed the way how setup is enabled and disabled. few just happy this is working now. hope this helps you spend less time that i did to find this solution.