# Missing mbstring in PHP 5.6 CentOS 6.8

Tags: centos6, php-extension, php-5.6, mbstring

I got the following error from one of my PHP functions (PHP verion 5.6)

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()
```

It is one of the mbstring package functions. So I checked in the phpinfo(). There is no "mbsting". I tried to install mbstring by using the following command in my CentOS 6.8 server.

```
yum install php56w-mbstring
```

But it returns:

```
No package php56w-mbstring available. Error: Nothing to do
```

I also tried: `rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm`
Ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/732468/how-to-install-php56-on-centos-6-x86-64

I have also tried: [Cannot install mbstring php conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864265/cannot-install-mbstring-php-conflict)
but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your /etc/yum.conf
Just remove 'php*'

Comment: After this, it returns: Package php56w-mbstring-5.6.25-1.w6.x86_64 is obsoleted by php-mbstring-5.6.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 which is already installed. Nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

Same question I post over here: https://superuser.com/questions/1121176/installing-php-extension-mbstring-in-php-5-6-centos-6-8

All of these PHP configurations had done through EazyApache. There are some unusual changes because of installing/upgrades through EazyApache (rather installing/upgrades doing directly on the server). So have to follow EazyApache to install new modules. For how to install module through EazyApache, Ref: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/enable-install-mbstring-module.158165/